# Efficient IDE for a small open source website project with one contributor

Tags: web-development, ide

Microsoft Azure present a clean integrated process but I wonder if this is really more efficient for small projects.

Could IDE have the advantage of being usable in any computer without the need of a git pull each time as long as there is only one user.

Local IDE are free for a big power but I'm changing computers a lot.

Features needed include Python Django coding, testing the code, git and deployment of a website custom code.

Price range... This is a non profit project with no funds.

It should run on Windows X. Android and Ubuntu would be nice too.

Comment: Done. Please ask if more information is needed. This is for a very basic Python site that interact with Wikidata API.

Comment: Thanks, reopened. Note that we don't feature product comparisons (see [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)), so I edited the title slightly. Good luck then! Should any more details be needed, those home in that area will voice them :)

Comment: For Python, absolutely nothing beats the free community edition of PyCharm